# Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect - Custom Reply Number

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is it possible to configure custom reply number in an SMS message? So despite the fact that users receive a message from one number, is it possible that their reply is sent to another real number (outside Marketing Cloud)?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no - the longcode/shortcode provisioned for your account, which you are sending from, are the only numbers your recipients can reply to.

Answer (score 1):

Per Lukas response - you can't. You can however achieve something similiar with:

1. Sending your message with custom from name
2. At the end of message add text asking for response like `reply to +XX XXX XXX XXX`

Using custom name will prevent customer from replying directly. This way you can point reply to selected number, even one that is not provisioned with SFMC.